# Javascript Intval Show/Hide Flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm trying to cycle real fast through a series of images to produce an animation using the below setInterval. However, if I move focus away from the browser tab and then back again, the animation flickers.

I saw a thread about using "real time" to catch the animation up, but since mine uses a simple show/hide, I wasn't sure how that applied.

```
var animation = setInterval(function(){

    var visible = $j('#container img:visible');
    var next    = visible.next('img');

    if(next.length <= 0) next = $j('#container img:first');

    next.show();
    visible.hide();

},64);
```

Any thoughts on how to combat the flickering?

Comment: By "move away from the browser" do you mean the browser tab looses focus?

Comment: Test for the existence of `window.requestAnimationFrame` first, and use that if it exists.

Comment: You can load all the images into the cache, waiting for all of their onload events to take place Asynchronously.

Comment: [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/u0vnqa8g/) using RequestAnimationFrame. If the window is visible and the update doesn't take too long, it will update at 60fps.

Comment: @jsve when I change to another tab or window, then go back, the flickering occurs

Comment: @AustinMullins the JSFiddle example is flickering a lot for me. I'm also looking at something that transitions slower than 60fps

Comment: The requestAnimationFrame callback is passed a timestamp you can use to decide whether to redraw.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, JavaScript animation can be handled a number of ways. One approach involves using a timing function such as setTimeout or setInterval to adjust styling every couple milliseconds. Another approach creates a loop that changes styling as many times as possible along the animation’s time frame. The logic of both of these approaches is to throw a large number of animation frames at the browser, so that it hopefully renders smooth-looking motion.

So, even though the browser renders as many frames of the animation as possible, the dropped frames still make for a choppy-looking animation, which is not to mention the performance implications of overloading the processor with as many tasks as possible.

In reality, it’s actually better to render fewer frames, provided they are rendered consistently. That’s because our eyes pick up these subtle variations, and a few dropped frames tend to stick out more than an overall lower frame rate. That’s where HTML5′s requestAnimationFrame API comes in.

Here is an example for your scenario:

```
 function animation(){

        var visible = $('#container img:visible');
        var next    = visible.next('img');

        if(next.length <= 0) next = $('#container img:first');

        next.show();
        visible.hide();

    };

   setInterval(function() {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);
   }, 64);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/vasadiqohu/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: I'm still getting a flicker effect using this method. To clarify, the flickering only happens when I've navigated away from the browser tab for a few seconds, and then returned,